# Emacs print javascript object properties or object outline in a buffer

Tags: javascript, emacs, editor, buffer

I have a javascript object, like so:

```
var myObj = {
    prop1 : 'abc',
    prop2: function(){
              return true;
           },
    prop3: function(){},
    ... // and so on
};
```

Is there a way in emacs to see a list of all the properties `myObj` has? And I can click on that property and it takes me to the occurrence in the javascript file. Something on the lines of `M-x occur`, which shows you "clickable" occurrences in a new buffer.

I could do `M-x list-js-props myObj`, and it opens up the aforementioned buffer.

Comment: How do you intend to use this? I can think of a few things that might help, but none to do exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: One use case can be where I am writing a method, say "prop19" that does something and I recall that such a functionality was already written in the same object, "myObj", 3 weeks ago. I can't recall the name of that method. So, I could use this and then see the list and then go, "Ah! 'prop5' has the functionality already. Let me look at that function".

Comment: Some editors, like Eclipse, have the "ctrl-click" combination that lets you navigate into methods/classes. I think Emacs does not have that feature.

Comment: Actually, Emacs does have standard keybindings for this (`M-.` to find a thing's definition and `M-,` to go back to where you were), but these bindings generally rely on external, language-specific tools to know where to go. `TAGS` files are one common option; for JavaScript I recommend Tern, as outlined in my answer below.

Comment: @fenderplayer Try `M-x imenu RET TAB`. Function names won't be grouped by objects, but this will give you "the major definitions in a file by name". More info on Imenu [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Imenu.html).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of anything that exactly does what you're after, but there are a few things you can try:

1. [The speedbar](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Speedbar.html) should show you functions¹ (though it does not show other properties).

   Start it with `M-x speedbar`, then expand nodes by clicking on the "+" icon. Clicking on a function name should take you to the matching occurrence in your buffer.

   Speedbar works best if you are using a GUI version of Emacs, since it starts a new frame. If you are working in a console, check out [SrSpeedbar](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SrSpeedbar).
2. You could use a standalone JavaScript analyzer like [Tern](http://ternjs.net/) [with Auto Complete](https://github.com/marijnh/tern/blob/master/emacs/tern-auto-complete.el) (or [with Company](https://github.com/proofit404/company-tern)) to quickly get suggestions, e.g.

   ```
   var myObj = {
       foo = // Hrm, what do I want?
   };

   otherObj. // See completions of otherObj here, find the one you want,
             // and complete.
   ```

   Once you've completed the other object you can use `tern-find-definition` (bound to `M-.` by default) to go to the property's definition, and `tern-pop-find-definition` (bound to `M-,` by default) to return.

   *Note: I didn't have much luck installing Tern via MELPA a few weeks ago. Instead, I followed [these instructions from the Tern website](http://ternjs.net/doc/manual.html#emacs).*
3. Finally, [`js2-mode`](https://github.com/mooz/js2-mode) may offer some help, though I wasn't able to find anything obvious. It is likely the most easy to modify to your needs using elisp, though.

¹Speedbar shows my JavaScript functions out of the box on Emacs 24.3.50.1 on Ubuntu.